# ArrayList remove except if contains character

Tags: java, android, if-statement, arraylist, remove-if

**Android Studio - Java**

How can I remove all entries from an ArrayList except the ones that contain  certain characters independently from upper and lower case?

```
String[] numbers = new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve"};

ArrayList arrayList=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(numbers));


ArrayList.remove();
```

E.g. if I choose the letters "Ne" I would like to remove all the entries from the arraylist except the entries containing the charachter string "ne".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In android ,for non java-8

1.) Traverse you array values

2.) Apply `toLowerCase()` to convert value to lowercase and Check if it contains `ne` , if no then remove the element from list

```
for (String s: numbers) {
    if (!s.toLowerCase().contains("ne")) {
        arrayList.remove(s);
    }
}
```

list elements

```
One
Nine
```

---

Java 8

1.) Never use [`Raw type`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

2.) Apply the above logic in `filter`

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(numbers));
List<String> non_ne = arrayList.stream()
                    .filter(x->!x.toLowerCase().contains("ne"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This code actually worked for me! Awesome, thank you so much!! :)

Comment: i am glad that i could help , happy coding

Answer (score 2):

You can use a stream

```
arrayList.stream().filter(x -> x.indexOf("ne") !=-1).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: contain certain characters independently from upper and lower case

Comment: Unfortunately, this code doesn't work for me since Android doesn't allow me to use Lambda expression.. Thank you anyway for your suggestion!

Comment: if you want `lambda` then you can use [retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code I am thinking you are probably better off not adding them in the first place. you are effectively saying:

```
String[] numbers = new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three", ...}; //array
List list = Arrays.asList(numbers) //create a list
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList<>(list); //create an ArrayList

//remove those not matching from the ArrayList
```

I would prefer the approach of only adding the ones I need to be in the list:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); //a LinkedList may be more appropriate 
for (String number : numbers) {
    if (number.toLowerCase().contains("ne")) {
        list.add(number );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is certainly helpful in other cases, however it doesn't really solve my problem. Thank you anyway for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
List <String> filtered = arrayList.stream().filter(x -> x.contains("ne")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: contain certain characters independently from upper and lower case

Comment: Unfortunately, this code doesn't work for me since Android doesn't allow me to use Lambda expression.. Thank you anyway for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Iterator<String> iter = arrayList.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
  String s = iter.next();
  if (s.toLowerCase().contains("ne")) iter.remove();
}
```